# How to aggregate matrices which have different dimensions? [R]

Tags: r, matrix

I have a few hundred thousands of matrices in a list which should be aggregated by group identifier. For instance, there are two matrices with different dimentions.

```
a <- matrix(c(1:12),nrow=3,ncol=4,dimnames=list(c(0:2),c(0:3)))
b <- matrix(c(1:6),nrow=2,ncol=3,dimnames=list(c(0:1),c(0:2)))

> a
  0 1 2  3
0 1 4 7 10
1 2 5 8 11
2 3 6 9 12
> b
  0 1 2
0 1 3 5
1 2 4 6
```

Do you know how to aggregate those matrices to obtain following matrix in a simple way?

```
c <- a + b
> c
   0  1  2  3
0  2  7 12 10
1  4  9 14 11
2  3  6  9 12
```

It may not be such a difficult question, however I could not find the solution.  
Row and column names start from 0 which sequentially step-up by 1 but maximum number varies based on each element. Unmatched dimentions in smaller matrices can be padded by 0.  
I suppose I can aggregate them by group but cannot aggregate matrices with different dimentions.

Comment: Most of matrices have different numbers of row and columns. I edited the post.

Comment: so the "unmatched" dimensions should be filled with 0?

Comment: If you mean "unmatched" dimensions as 6 values in row=2 and col=3 in matrix b in the post, the answer is yes.

Comment: Thank you for prompt responses. I understand that it should have the same dimensions first before aggregation.

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions. I marked @G. Grothendieck's idea due to its simplicity. However all of suggestions worked well. Thank you for your support!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some alternative solutions:

**1)** Convert each to long form giving `both` and then use `tapply` to aggregate and convert back to wide form:

```
both <- rbind(as.data.frame.table(a), as.data.frame.table(b))
tapply(both[[3]], both[-3], sum, default = 0)
```

giving:

```
    Var2
Var1 0 1  2  3
   0 2 7 12 10
   1 4 9 14 11
   2 3 6  9 12
```

**2)** This creates a matrix `zero` having the shape of the result and then defines a function `upleft` which inserts its first argument into the upper left of zero.  Finally we add them together.

```
upleft <- function(x, zero) replace(zero, cbind(c(row(x)), c(col(x))), x)
zero <- array(0, pmax(dim(a), dim(b)))
upleft(a, zero) + upleft(b, zero)
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    7   12   10
[2,]    4    9   14   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function which takes in two matrices and pads them with 0's to make their dimensions the same. Then it sums them. This can be used with `Reduce` to sum many together in one operation.

First, get the max number of rows and the max number of columns of the two matrices. Then, a matrix of 0's is created with these max dimensions. Then, only the sub-matrix that matches each input is populated. The matrices are summed and returned.

```
sum_ragged_matrix = function(m1,m2){
  m1r = nrow(m1r)
  m2r = nrow(m2r)

  m1c = ncol(m1c)
  n2c = ncol(m2c)

  max_rows = max(c(m1r,m2r))
  max_cols = max(c(m1c,m2c))
  t1 = matrix(0,nrow = max_rows,ncol = max_cols)
  t2 = t1
  t1[1:m1r,1:m1c] = m1
  t2[1:m2r,1:m2c] = m2
  return(t1+t2)
}

a = matrix(c(1:12),nrow=3,ncol=4,dimnames=list(c(0:2),c(0:3)))
b = matrix(c(1:6),nrow=2,ncol=3,dimnames=list(c(0:1),c(0:2)))
c = matrix(c(1:4),nrow=2,ncol=2,dimnames=list(c(0:1),c(0:1)))

Reduce(sum_ragged_matrix,list(a=a,b=b,c=c),init=matrix(0,nrow=1,ncol=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this function that takes any two matrices, adjusts the number of rows and columns, pads them with 0s, and then adds them up.

```
sum_mat = function(a, b){
    temp = matrix(data = 0, nrow = max(nrow(a), nrow(b)), ncol = max(ncol(a), ncol(b)))
    temp_a = temp
    temp_a[1:nrow(a), 1:ncol(a)] = a
    temp_b = temp
    temp_b[1:nrow(b), 1:ncol(b)] = b
    temp_a + temp_b
}


> a
  0 1 2  3
0 1 4 7 10
1 2 5 8 11
2 3 6 9 12

> b
  0 1 2
0 1 3 5
1 2 4 6

c = sum_mat(a, b)

> c
   0  1  2  3
0  2  7 12 10
1  4  9 14 11
2  3  6  9 12
```