# How can I sum multiple matrices of different dimensions in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add two matrices with different dimension in R. Ideally, the system should equate two matrices adding missing rows/columns, filled with zeros. For instance, if we have one matrix with 1:4 rows and another with 1:5 rows and their number of columns is identical. So to add the two matrices we need to add to the first matrix the fifth row full of zeros.
Could you please help.

```
#Matrix1 
a11<-matrix(c(419371623,    10990236,   29346292,   0,  0, 39386246.52, 0, 0,0  ,0,0,   0,  0,  0,  30174248.77,0,  27839925.91,    0   ,0  ,112921829.5),4,5,dimnames = list(c(1,2,3,5),c(1,2,3,4,5)),byrow=TRUE)

#Matrix 2    
a22<-matrix(c(853624485,    0, 766111,0, 0, 20240075.89 ,0, 4839059.2,0,    2062687.122 ,0, 0,0 ,0  ,0  ,7282484.458,0, 18738621.67 ,0  ,0),5,4,byrow=TRUE, list(c(1:5),c(1:4)))

#Expected Result:
res<- matrix(c(1272996108,  10990236,   30112402.72,    0,  0,
               39386247,    20240075.89,    0,  48390599.21,    0,
                      0,    2062687.122 ,0, 0,  30174249,
                      0,    27839926,   0,  7282484.458,    112921830,
                      0,    18738622,   0,  0,  0), 5, 5, byrow=TRUE, dimnames = list(1:5,1:5)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to aggregate matrices which have different dimensions? \[R\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51383805/how-to-aggregate-matrices-which-have-different-dimensions-r)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own function to perform this:

```
`%+%` <- function(a, b){
  i <- dim(a)
  j <- dim(b)
  out <- pmax(i,j)
  valid <- pmin(i,j)
  result <- matrix(0, out[1], out[2])
  
  v_row <- seq(valid[1])
  v_col <- seq(valid[2])
  
  result[v_row, v_col] <- a[v_row, v_col] + b[v_row, v_col]

  ind1 <- which(result[seq(i[1]), seq(i[2])] == 0 & a!=0, TRUE)
  result[ind1] <- a[ind1]
  
  ind2 <- which(result[seq(j[1]), seq(j[2])] == 0 & b!=0, TRUE)
  result[ind2] <- b[ind2]
  
  result
}


a11%+%a22
           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1272996108 10990236 30112403       0         0
[2,]   39386247 20240076        0 4839059         0
[3,]          0  2062687        0       0  30174249
[4,]          0 27839926        0 7282484 112921830
[5,]          0 18738622        0       0         0


s1 <- matrix(1,3,5)
s2 <- matrix(2, 5,2)
s1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1
s2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    2    2
[4,]    2    2
[5,]    2    2
s1 %+% s2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    3    1    1    1
[2,]    3    3    1    1    1
[3,]    3    3    1    1    1
[4,]    2    2    0    0    0
[5,]    2    2    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a shorter/better way to make the dimension of both the matrix equal but here is one way.

```
n <- max(ncol(a11), ncol(a22))
m <- max(nrow(a11), nrow(a22))

if(m > ncol(a11)) a11 <- cbind(a11, matrix(0, ncol = m - ncol(a11), nrow = nrow(a11)))
if(m > ncol(a22)) a22 <- cbind(a22, matrix(0, ncol = m - ncol(a22), nrow = nrow(a22)))
if(n > nrow(a11)) a11 <- rbind(a11, matrix(0, ncol = ncol(a11), nrow = n - nrow(a11)))
if(n > nrow(a22)) a11 <- rbind(a11, matrix(0, ncol = ncol(a12), nrow = n - nrow(a22)))
```

Now `a11` and `a22` are of same dimension so you can add them :

```
a11 + a22

#           1        2        3       4         5
#1 1272996108 10990236 30112403       0         0
#2   39386247 20240076        0 4839059         0
#3          0  2062687        0       0  30174249
#5          0 27839926        0 7282484 112921830
#           0 18738622        0       0         0
```

Answer (score 0):

After initializing res to zero, I am adding the matrices by indices.

Easily extendable to add more matrices.

```
# initilize res
res <- matrix(0, nrow = max(nrow(a11), nrow(a22)), 
        ncol = max(ncol(a11), ncol(a22)))   

# index of a11
inds <- which(!is.na(a11), arr.ind = T)
res[inds] <- res[inds] + a11[inds]

# index of a22
inds <- which(!is.na(a22), arr.ind = T)
res[inds] <- res[inds] + a22[inds]

# repeat for a33 etc if there's more.
```

Results with `a11` and `a22`

```
> res
           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1272996108 10990236 30112403       0         0
[2,]   39386247 20240076        0 4839059         0
[3,]          0  2062687        0       0  30174249
[4,]          0 27839926        0 7282484 112921830
[5,]          0 18738622        0       0         0
```